# How can I handle a web application that connects to many SQL Server databases?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-pooling

I am building an ASP.NET web application that will use SQL Server for data storage.  I am inheriting an existing structure and I am not able to modify it very much.  The people who use this application are individual companies who have paid to use the application.  Each company has about 5 or 10 people who will use the application.  There are about 1000 companies.  The way that the system is currently structured, every company has their own unique database in the SQL Server instance.  The structure of each database is the same.  I don't think that this is a good database design but there is nothing I can do about it.  There are other applications that hit this database and it would be quite an undertaking to rewrite the DB interfaces for all of those apps.

So my question is how to design the architecture for the new web app.  There are times of the month where the site will get a lot of traffic.  My feeling is that the site will not perform well at these times because I am guessing that when we have 500 people from different companies accessing the site simultaneously that they will each have their own unique database connection because they are accessing different SQL Server databases with different connection strings.  SQL Server will not use any connection pooling.  My impression is that this is bad.

What happens if they were to double their number of customers?  How many unique database connections can SQL Server handle?  Is this a situation where I should tell the client that they *must* redesign this if they want to remain scalable?

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create separate connections for every DB

I have an app that uses multiple DBs on the same server.  I prefix each query with a "USE dbName; "

I've even run queries on two separate DB's in the same call.

As for calling stored procs, it's a slightly different process. Since you can't do

```
     Use myDB; spBlahBLah
```

Instead you have to explicity change the DB in the connection object.  In .Net it looks something like this:

```
     myConnection.ChangeDatabase("otherDBName");
```

then call your stored procedure.

Comment: Hmmm...interesting.  So what database does your app connect to?  Master?

Comment: With that situation can you use stored procedures effectively?  It would seem that you wouldn't be able to because your SQL would have to be built on the fly every time.

Comment: It connects to the "default" database, not the master.  But to be safe, it still calles USE even if its querying the default.

Comment: I think this is a good idea. **However**, if you have separate connections for each database, you don't have to wait for a statement for ClientA to complete to execute a statement for ClientB. I, personally, wouldn't go with this method.

Comment: @Brad, that is incorrect. You can indeed run multiple queries against the same database, it's all taken care of via connection pooling.

Comment: @Neil, not if you follow your sample. You changed the database for the entire connection meaning that if you switch to ClientA, you can't execute any ClientB code until you can switch it back. No?

Comment: @Brad, why not? The db doesnt care if you switch it back after a call is made.  It's not going to interupt a currently running query and retoractively change it's db.

Comment: @Neil, okay, I see that logic (so +1 for your answer) *However* with 5000 potential users you're going to run thread-safe issues. You will need to lock the connection from just before changing the database until you execute the statement.

Comment: Brad, I think you misunderstand how connection pooling works.  It's not a single instance for every connection an application needs.  Its an instance reserved for every active user.  When a connection goes idle, it gets thrown back into the pool, to be used by the next user.

Comment: And if the pool hits its limit, the next user waits (if even for only a split second) until another query is done, freeing up the next connection.

Comment: @Neil, okay, so how does SQL know the difference between me and you? Is each and every user authenticating? Or is he using a single username/password the connection. If so, then to SQL they're all the same "user" and don't get separate connections from the pool.

Comment: Brad, I STILL think you need to reestablish what you think about how connection pooling actually works.  Even on sites that have a single user/pass and never switch DB, still create multiple connections in the pool.

Comment: @Neil, I understand that when you create a connection pool (i.e. IDbConnection) you can run multiple concurrent statements within it. My point is that the Database is set at the **pool** level, and between the time that you call `myConnection.ChangeDatabase("overHere")` and `myConnection.Open()` someone on another thread (this is the web) is destined to call `myConnection.ChangeDatabase("overThere")` and your `myConnection.Open()` is not going to connect to what you think it will.

Comment: @Neil, my entire point about SQL not knowing the difference between users was your use of the phrase "It[']s an instance reserved for every active user". Connections within the pool aren't 'reserved' for users in the system but more likely threads. But the idea is that if you `.Close()` your connection, it goes back into the pool (which in my experience is not always foolproof -- but maybe I'm the fool).

Comment: by user I meant vistors to the site (so yes, threads) and thread safety would only come into play if you were actually sharing a specific instance of the connection object across threads (which is bad practice anyways) I've had a site using multiple DBs on the same connection pool, that switches the db at will, with hundreds of concurrent users, since 2007, and never once has a query executed on the wrong db.  The connection pool is thread safe.

Comment: @Neil, in my practice, I use a singleton database connection at the website level so as to avoid recreating it on each call. What you're saying is you create a new connection for each request? If so, then of course you're thread safe.

Comment: a singleton connection is actually bad for performance, and defeats the purpose of the thread pool. There have been dozens of tests to prove this.

Comment: @Neil, I appreciate your understanding on this topic. If you could point me to resources on this, I would appreciate it. I'm not really understanding how you could benefit from connection pooling if you create a new connection for each thread (i.e. each postback). You would only be making, say, 1-10 calls on that connection, right?

Comment: @Brad, you have to abstract it a little bit, every time you do new SqlConnection(), you are creating a new local instance, but NOT a new physical connection (that part comes from, and is managed by, the pool)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Comment: And when you do a close() or dispose(), you arent really getting rid of the connection, you are only killing the local reference to it, the pool will still keep the physical connection open.

Comment: So here's a follow up question regarding this: does anyone know if it is possible to follow Neil's solution using the Microsoft Data Access Application Block?  I was hoping to use the DAAB, but I am wondering if the DAAB is sort of predicated on accessing one database at a time and it wouldn't make good use of connection pooling.  Does anyone know about how the DAAB would work in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you have a single database for common items. Here, I hope you have a `Clients` table with `IsEnabled`, `Logo`, `PersonToCallWhenTheyDontPayBills`, etc. Add a column for `Database` (i.e. catalog) and while you're at it, `Server`. You web application will point to the **common** database when starting up and build the list of database connetions per client. Programmatically build your database connection strings with the `Server` and `Database` columns in the table.

---

**UPDATE:**

After my discussion with @Neil, I want to point out that my method assumes a singleton database connection. If you don't do this then it would be silly to follow my advice.

Comment: Ok.  I understand what you are saying.  But my question is more about scaling and performance.  I can set it up like you suggest but that doesn't solve the performance issue.  Can the database handle 500 or 1000 simultaneous connections to 500 or 1000 different databases?  My gut feeling is that this is a bad setup.

Comment: I think you mean, can the **server** handle 1000 different connections to 1000 different databases. The answer is yes, the server can handle it. However connection pooling (defined in the connection string -- 500 by default) is set at the **connection** level. If you have all the clients on the same connection, you're going to run into the upper limit rather quickly it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling is a complex issue. However why are you not scaling the web aspect as well? Then the connection pooling is limited to the web application.

edit:
I'm talking about the general case here. I know tha pooling occurs at many levels, not just the IDbConnection (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526617/are-ado-net-2-0-connection-pools-pre-application-domain-or-per-process). I was wondering whether the questioner had considered scaling at the we application level.

Comment: Connection pooling is limited to the IDbConnection.